# Nested list of constant strings in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

Any way I can store this data in a clean way, and preferably use variable names instead of strings as keys to avoid typos? E.g. `UNITED_STATES = "201"` instead of `"United States" = "201"`.

```
{
    "countries": {
         "id": "123",
         "data" {
             "United States": "201"
             "Canada": "202",
         }
    },
    "departments": { ... }
}
```

I started with `KeyValuePairs` like this, but nesting data in here seems like a bad idea.

```
private static readonly List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> CategoryIds = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Countries", "123"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Departments", "124")
};
```

Comment: There are sites that will generate c# classes for you based on JSON. That way you can match the input http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: What about using of `Enum` for that?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I was thinking about it. Unfortunately I cannot store strings within enums.

Comment: The Json is not Valid missing `:` after data, missing `,` after `"201"`, unexpected `,` after `"202"`. Data look like it could be an array. but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches to deserialize JSON here.

**Strong typing** approach (good approach):

```
public class A
{
     public B Countries {get;set;}
     public C Departments {get;set;}
}

public class B
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public D Data {get;set;}
}

...

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json);
```

You create DTO objects manually and just expect them to deserialize successfully.

**Dynamic** approach (bad but sometimes acceptable approach):

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

var data = result.countries.data;
```

You create some "bag of things" (*dynamic* is basically a bunch of hierarchical Dictionary wrapped into syntax sugar cane), don't really care about all of them, and just want some of its properties.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use json.net `JObject`?

It allows you to work with dynamic objects and convert them to and from json strings

Documentation for `JObject`
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm

Nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dictionary<k,v>` for this purpose along with a `enum` like below probably

```
enum CountryVal
{
 UnitesStates,
 Canada
}
```

With a model structure like

```
public class Countries
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<CountryVal, int> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Departments
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Countries countries { get; set; }
    public Departments departments { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public class as below and you can then call country value like `CountriesConstants.UNITED_STATES` in your code and if you need to change the value just update it in `CountriesConstants` class

```
public class CountriesConstants
{
    public const string UNITED_STATES = "201";
    public const string Canada = "202";
    //Add More
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NJsonSchema is a library that will enable you to generate code in csharp as well as few other languages from a standard json schema. It is very powerful and configurable, and can pave most of the way on your behalf. But as i said it will expect an standard json schema as for the source of generation.

```
var schema = NJsonSchema.JsonSchema4.FromFileAsync(filename);
var generator = new CSharpGenerator(schema.Result);
var file = generator.GenerateFile();
```

Above is the minimum amount of code required to generate csharp classes from json schema. you can define settings and pass to the generator function to service your special needs of course.

github page for this library:
[NJsonSchema github](https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema)

Nuget page:
[NJsonSchema Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NJsonSchema/)